# R command prompt not working windows

Tags: r

I try to run R from command prompt but its doing nothing. need R CMD INSTALL to work but it wont. Does anyone know why?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>which R
/c/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/bin/x64/R

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>R.exe

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>
```

Comment: The R executable probably isn't in your PATH environment variable. [This blog post](https://stevemosher.wordpress.com/step-six-fixing-your-path/) might help (and [here's one for editing your PATH](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm))

Comment: its in my path, which is why it showed up in the which command

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder `/c/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/bin/x64/` and try `./R.exe`

Comment: . is not a windows thing, but I tried in cygwin, dos and msys and only in msys does it work